# Storing Date from an <asp:TextBox> in MSSQL 'Date' field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I'm really having trouble taking a date from an `<asp:TextBox>` and storing it in a 'DATE' type field in my MSSQL database. Currently my code is ignoring my textbox value, and storing the current date. I hope someone can help!

Here is my code, I collect the date like this:

```
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
end = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text);
```

And then this line is used in conjunction with my query, to bind the parameter.

```
AppendNews.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@show_to", end));
```

Just out of interest, when I run the program on local host, all works fine!

Regards

Adam

Comment: you want to take DAY from DATE right...? Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: When is this not working?  Is there an exception thrown?

Comment: is this doesn't work DateTime end; rather than Datetime end = Datetime.Now;

Comment: Change `AppendNews.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@show_to", end));` to `AppendNews.Parameters.AddWithValue("@show_to", end);` or specify the SqlDbType as your date or datetime2 value.

Comment: Apologies, collect a DATE and store it. The problem only occurs when I run the script live on the website, however when I run the script on the ASP Development Server in Visual studio, all works fine. No error is displayed online - only the current date is stored in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually because the culture of the ASP server did not match the database server. To resolve this problem the culture much be set in the web.config file of the ASP project. Do this like so, as part of the `<system.web>` wrapper.

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"/>
```

Then, you can reference this value in your scripts by this line, when you are collecting the value from your

```
DateTime dFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
bool isDateValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
txtEndDate.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
DateTimeStyles.None,out end)
```

This will try to parse the string using the defined format and return false if the format is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Use stronger error checking [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx). Your DateTime might not be getting parsed right.

```
DateTime end;

if(!DateTime.TryParse(txtEndDate.Text, out end))
{
    throw new FormatException("End Date must be in a valid format");
}
```

I would use [SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) or specify your `SqlDbType`.

```
AppendNews.Parameters.AddWithValue("@show_to", end);
```

Comment: None, of these solutions worked. I believe the problem to be with the formatting of the date variable. The server returns MM/dd/yyyy and locally dd/MM/yyyy is returned. Conversion between the two appears to be failing.

Comment: Are you using a SqlConnection or OdbcConnection? What Sql Type is your parameter `@show_to` (e.g. Date, Datetime2, etc)? What does the stored procedure do with the parameter? What is the error sql is outputting? When is it outputting the error?

Comment: Could it be that there is a difference in the way your date format is set up at the operating system level between your development and production servers?